# How i can disable JPanel when JFrame Start

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I want to disable a JPanel at the start of JFrame
I know the code that I have to use but I do not know where I should put it

```
public class Fenetre1 extends JFrame {
//code JFrame
    private class Affichage implements ActionListener {
//action
}
}
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
Fenetre1 f = new Fenetre1 ();
f.panel.setEnabled(false);

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can setEnabled(false) when you create the JPanel.  If you want to toggle enabling the JPanel, you should probably use a listener.

Notes from Java documentation (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html)

- Note: Disabling a component does not disable its children.
- Note: Disabling a lightweight component does not prevent it from receiving MouseEvents.

  ```
  JFrame jframe = new JFrame();

  JPanel jpanel = new JPanel();
  jpanel.setEnabled(false);

  jframe.add(jpanel);
  ```

Comment: precisely my panel contains a table of components that's why I used the solution that I posted. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `JPanel` can't be focused but *Object*s like `JTextField` or `JTextArea` are focus-able.

If you have some objects like those in the `JPanel` , then use `textArea.setFocusable(false)`.

And you can try `jPanel.setEnabled(false)`.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer inspired me a bit, I use a component table in the JPanel
so,I went through the entire table and disabled each component
I put the code in the class inheriting the JFrame:

```
 for(int j= 0;j<tab_component.length;j++) 
            {
                    tab_buttonsOperateur[j].setEnabled(false);
            }
```

thanks anyway